# incorrect work of items datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the code:

```
<div id = 'block1'><input type = 'text' class = 'datepicker' id = 'mydate'></div>
<div id = 'block2'><input type = 'text' class = 'datepicker' id = 'mydate'></div>

...

$('#block1 #mydate').datepicker(...);
$('#block2 #mydate').datepicker(...);
```

When I set the properties for each element (for example, sets the date), then everything is working correctly - the right svoeystvo set for the selected item.

But while working with the element, when the pop-up dialog, I select the date, the date is not established in the selected item, and in the very first.

Can you fix something like this behavior? Or just using unique identifiers  (this is not very much like)?

```
<div id = 'block1'><input type = 'text' class = 'datepicker' id = 'mydate1'></div>
<div id = 'block2'><input type = 'text' class = 'datepicker' id = 'mydate2'></div>

...

$('#block1 #mydate1').datepicker(...);
$('#block2 #mydate2').datepicker(...);
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs on a page, try targeting the class instead.

Comment: yes :(
only unique ID, 

unique combination of class + id does not work correctly (feature of jquery-ui datepicker)

Comment: `$('.datepicker').datepicker()` works. Plus `$('#block1 .datepicker').datepicker()` should work